# Using not(selector) on dynamically create element

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code basically edit a table cell.
I want to use the not() method so that everytime I click outside the temporary input created I replace it with a table cell. I guess the code run in a block and doesn't detect any input with an id of "replace" so how can I fix that ?
Also I want to store the element (th or td) that fire the first event(dblclick) so that I can use it to replace the input with the right type of cell but it seems to only stores the element that first triggers the event and I don't really understand why.

Full code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wjpo9k1t/1/)

```
$(function () {
  $(document).on("dblclick", "th, td", function (event) {
    var cellText = $(this).text();
    $(this).replaceWith("<input type='text' id='replace' value='" + cellText + "'>");
    var $typeCell = $(event.currentTarget);      // Store element which trigger the event     
    $("body").not("#replace").on("click", function () {       // .not() method
      cellText = $("#replace").val();
      if ($typeCell.is("th")) {
        $("#replace").replaceWith("<th scope='col'>" + cellText + "</th>");
      }
      else {
        $("#replace").replaceWith("<td>" + cellText + "</td>");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: You're binding a new, additional `click` handler every single time you open a textbox. This will rapidly get out of control. Anyway, since there is only one `body` and it doesn't have the ID `#replace`, your `.not()` is useless. Instead, bind to `body` *once*, check if `#replace` exists but is not the target of the event, then proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified HTML and JavaScript to avoid any possible errors. The correct practice is to wrap all `th`'s in a `thead` and all `td`'s in `tbody`.

```js
$(document).on("dblclick", "th, td", function(event) {
  var cellText = $(this).text();
  $(this).replaceWith("<input type='text' id='replace' value='" + cellText + "'>");
});

$("body").on("click", function() {
  if (event.target.id != 'replace' && $('#replace').length != 0) {
    var cellText = $("#replace").val();
    if ($('#replace').parents().is('thead'))
      $("#replace").replaceWith("<th scope='col'>" + cellText + "</th>");
    else
      $("#replace").replaceWith("<td>" + cellText + "</td>");
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 20px;
  min-width: 100px;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 4px;
}

th {
  background: springgreen;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 127, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Uno</th>
        <th scope="col">Dos</th>
        <th scope="col">Tres</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Data1</td>
        <td>Data2</td>
        <td>Data3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data4</td>
        <td>Data5</td>
        <td>Data6</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```